# Desingularization of subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety. Let $Y \subset X$ is a singular closed subvariety of $X$. Does there exist a birational morphism $\pi: \widetilde{X} \to X$, such that the proper preimage $\widetilde{Y}$ of $Y$ is smooth? In addition, can we obtain $\pi$ as a composition of blow-ups with smooth centers?

Comment: This is called "embedded resolution of singularities". A good reference is Kollar's book.

Comment: I don't know who that author is whom Sasha mentions ... :),  but there is a very good book on the subject written by Kollár(!): http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8449.html

Comment: If there is an embedding of X into a regular variety Y. A strong desingularization of X a proper birational morphism from a regular variety $f:Y' \rightarrow Y$ satisfying the following conditions :
1) The transform $X′$ of $X$ is regular and transverse to the exceptional locus of the resolution morphism.
2)The restriction $f_{X'}:X' \rightarrow X$ is an isomorphism away from the singular points of X (thus they have the same function field).

Comment: The construction of $Y′$ is given by a succession of a blowing up of regular closed subvarieties of $Y$ or more strongly regular subvarieties of $X$, transverse to the exceptional locus of the previous blowings up.

Comment: Hironaka proved that the strong desingularization always exists for varieties of characteristic 0, but for varieties of characteristic p, this problem stills open in dimensions  4 or more and the construction of Hironaka was improved and actually we know that the construction of $Y′$ is functorial for smooth morphisms to $Y$ and embeddings of $Y$ into a larger variety and we know also that the morphism from $X′$ to $X$ does not depend on the embedding of $X$ in $Y$.

Comment: Sándor, now I can find it:) Sasha, thank you.

Comment: Adel,  if you wich to post this as an answer, I will accept it.